# check sum calculator doesn't get the last digit

Tags: java, math, operators

So when I put in a 12-digit long number it calculates the check sum correctly. But if I put in a 13-digit long number it does something wrong.

```
public static void checksum(long l) {

    long x1   = l / 100000000000l % 10;
    long x2   = l / 10000000000l % 10;
    long x3   = l / 1000000000 % 10;
    long x4   = l / 100000000 % 10;
    long x5   = l / 10000000 % 10;
    long x6   = l / 1000000 % 10;
    long x7   = l / 100000 % 10;
    long x8   = l / 10000 % 10;
    long x9   = l / 1000 % 10;
    long x10  = l / 100 % 10; 
    long x11  = l / 10 % 10;
    long x12  = l / 1 % 10;
    long x13  = l  % 10;
    
   long calculation = x1+(x2*3)+x3+(x4*3)+x5+(x6*3)+x7+(x8*3)+x9+(x10*3)+x11+(x12*3)+x13;
    System.out.println(calculation);
}
```

Comment: Can you give example of given input, the output and the expected output ? And share the code of how you call the method, the error could be there too

Comment: When the input is 3729483022008 the expected output is 100.What I get is 107

Comment: Do you call with `3729483022008` or `3729483022008L`, I got 91 as result with that

Comment: `l / 1 % 10` is the same as `l % 10`.

Comment: I call with 3729483022008L

Comment: Could you please edit your original question to include the updates in your comments so future readers can benefit?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to use.  You were off by a factor of 10 in your initial modular computations.

```
checksum(3729483022008L);
    
    
public static void checksum(long l) {
        
        long x1   = l / 1000000000000L % 10;
        long x2   = l / 100000000000L % 10;
        long x3   = l / 10000000000L % 10;
        long x4   = l / 1000000000 % 10;
        long x5   = l / 100000000 % 10;
        long x6   = l / 10000000 % 10;
        long x7   = l / 1000000 % 10;
        long x8   = l / 100000 % 10;
        long x9   = l / 10000 % 10;
        long x10  = l / 1000 % 10; 
        long x11  = l / 100 % 10;
        long x12  = l / 10 % 10;
        long x13  = l / 1 % 10;
        
        long calculation = x1 + (x2 * 3) + x3 + (x4 * 3) + x5
                + (x6 * 3) + x7 + (x8 * 3) + x9 + (x10 * 3) + x11
                + (x12 * 3) + x13;
        
        System.out.println(calculation);
}
```

Prints

```
100
```

Answer (score 0):

That is normal because the to get the first digit, with `x1` you divide by `10^11`, but then you apply `%10`, with a number bigger that 10^13 (so 13-len or more) it  do not uses the new digits

```
System.out.println(l / 100000000000L);      // 37
System.out.println(l / 100000000000L % 10); // 7
```

---

The operation `number / ((long) Math.pow(10, i)) % 10` takes the `i-th` digit of `number`, so with 12 as the biggest one, you won't get the 13th or bigger

---

In fact this problem goes along the other that you used the last `8` twice, you need to shift all factors, multiply them by 10

```
public static void checkSum(long l) {

    long x1 = l / 1000000000000L % 10;
    long x2 = l / 100000000000L % 10;
    long x3 = l / 10000000000L % 10;
    long x4 = l / 1000000000 % 10;
    long x5 = l / 100000000 % 10;
    long x6 = l / 10000000 % 10;
    long x7 = l / 1000000 % 10;
    long x8 = l / 100000 % 10;
    long x9 = l / 10000 % 10;
    long x10 = l / 1000 % 10;
    long x11 = l / 100 % 10;
    long x12 = l / 10 % 10;
    long x13 = l % 10;

    long calculation = x1 + (x2 * 3) + x3 + (x4 * 3) + x5 + (x6 * 3) + x7 + (x8 * 3) + x9 +
        (x10 * 3) + x11 + (x12 * 3) + x13;
    System.out.println(calculation);

}
```

Comment: @sanandereas35 for what ? Use all digits after 12th one ? Remove %10``

Comment: If I remove the %10 after x2 and x1 (suppose thats what you meant) I get 1247 as an output

Comment: @sanandereas35 no just for x1, how do you get 100 ? Careful you use the last `8` twice, in x12 and in x13

Comment: @sanandereas35 just got it ? You need to shift all, by adding a 0 to all, to get the first digit, and not the 8 twice, look my edit

Comment: Sorry, the expected output is 92. If i remove the %10 from x1 I get:137. I found this german website where you can put in a number and calculate its check sum but with different factors so: 1*3+7*3+1*2.... :https://rechneronline.de/quersumme/gewichtet.php

Comment: @sanandereas35 I leave you to your tries, I've provided you the explanation, I won't debug and do tries for you ;)

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm confused. It would be nice if you could just show me the corrected version of my longs

Comment: @sanandereas35 I've put the new code in my post about 7mins ago